# How can I use class type with switch in java?

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
Variable var;
//var is initialized to an unknown class type, stored as a public variable named type.
//var = new Variable<Integer>(Integer.class, <some integer value>);
//var.type is equal to Integer.class

switch (var.type)
{
case Integer.class:
    //do some class specific stuff 
    break;
case Float.class:
    //do some class specific stuff
    break;
etc...
}
```

When I type the code out I get an error saying "Integer.class constant expression expected". I would like to use a switch block because it is cleaner that typing out:

```
if (var.type == Integer.class) {}
```

I am confused as to why the if block will compile without error while the switch block will not. I'm not entirely against using if blocks but its more a matter of my curiosity at this point. Thanks.

Comment: An `if` condition has different properties than a `case` label.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html - first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) states that, for a `switch` statement's *Expression*:

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte,
>   Short, Integer, String, or an enum type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `switch` statement for this. Only integer values, strings or enums can be used with `switch` `case` labels.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `switch` statement to compare class type of an object. You would have to live with `if-else` statements.